# Regex to find a somewhat recursive pattern

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Here's my string:

```
SELECT x FROM Table1 WHERE (SELECT y FROM Table2 LIMIT 1) > 15 LIMIT 4
```

Here's my regex:

```
SELECT .+ FROM .+ LIMIT (?<LIMITCOUNT>\d{1,4})
```

I want it to do 2 captures; one is the entire string and the other is the part in paranthesis, but it only captures the entire string. What's my way out?

Comment: what is your expected output..specify that..

Comment: @Candide: I see what u mean, but that makes results even worse.

Comment: By `the part in parentheses`, do you mean the parentheses in the string or the parentheses in the regex?

Comment: As I said, it should capture two groups. The entire string and the part in paranthesis becuz both conform to the pattern.

Comment: @Rawling: paranthesis in the string of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture it in the lookahead

```
(?=((?<=^|\s)SELECT .+? LIMIT \d{1,4}(?=\s|$)|(?<=\()SELECT .+? LIMIT \d{1,4}(?=\))))
```

This will capture 2 queries in your example!Access it using group 1

Try it [here](http://regexhero.net/tester/)

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that although it does capture two substrings, I see the same value of LIMITCOUNT group for both captures, i.e. 4.

Comment: @dotNET dont forger to add `@` before `"yourstring"`

Answer (score -1):

I see what you're getting at here. When you call `Matches` to get multiple matches, it doesn't search for matches "within" other matches; it finds the first match, then starts looking again *after the end* of that match, and so on.

I don't *believe* there's an out-of-the-box way of doing what you want, so you'll need to do it manually. You'll need to make a few changes:

1. Make your first `.+` non-greedy (`.+?`) so that the `FROM` matches the first `FROM`, not the second. At the moment it's matching the second `FROM`, and this meses up step 2:
2. Add another capture group around your second `.+`, e.g. `(?<PotentialNested>.+)`. Keep it greedy so the `LIMIT` matches the second `LIMIT`, not the first.
3. Write a method that, having checked the initial string for matches, continues to check these `PotentialNested` captures for further matches, recursively:

```
public static IEnumerable<Match> NestedMatches(this Regex regex, string input)
{
    var potentialNested = new Queue<string>();
    foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(input))
    {
        yield return m;
        potentialNested.Enqueue(m.Groups["PotentialNested"].Value);
    }
    while (potentialNested.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(potentialNested.Dequeue()))
        {
            yield return m;
            potentialNested.Enqueue(m.Groups["PotentialNested"].Value);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**: Actually, after all this, it still doesn't work if you have two nested terms next to each other, e.g.

```
SELECT x FROM Table1 WHERE
((SELECT y FROM Table2 LIMIT 1) + (SELECT y FROM Table2 LIMIT 1)) > 15
LIMIT 4
```

If this a potential input, you could try making sure your `PotentialNested` capture group balances brackets:

```
(?<PotentialNested>((?<BR>\()|(?<-BR>\))|[^()]*)+)
```

Comment: this is really not required..you dont need to do it manually..you can simply use lookahed that would handle any number of nested queries

Comment: -1 because, as Some1.Kill.The.DJ pointed out, lookahead *is* an out of the box way to get overlapping matches.

Comment: @Some1.Kill.The.DJ I see... I'm going to have to spend a while figuring out how yours works :p

Comment: @dan1111 On the other hand, mine allows for a second (or further) level of nesting, whereas Some1's doesn't appear to.

Comment: @Rawling, upon reflection, I agree that lookahead is not really adequate for nested matching in the general case.  I apologize for the downvote.